# nodes geographic coordinates with pgRouting Query

Tags: qgis, pgrouting, osm2pgsql, shortest-path

Can we get the coordinate of nodes belongs to shortest path???

I give brief description, I calculate the shortest path with A* algorithm using Pgrouting, but what I'm looking for coordinates (long, Lat) of all the nodes that belong to path???

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples how to join the result of a pgRouting query with its original table to return the geometry as part of the result, starting with the following example:

```
SELECT dijkstra.*, ways.name, ST_AsText(ways.the_geom)
FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT gid AS id, * FROM vehicle_net',
    (SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr WHERE osm_id = 61350413),
    (SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr WHERE osm_id = 61479912)
    ) AS dijkstra
LEFT JOIN ways
ON (edge = gid) ORDER BY seq;
```

In the example above the geometry is returned in WKT format with `ST_AsText(ways.the_geom)` but you could also get single lat/lon points using `ST_DumpPoints(ways.the_geom)` instead.